# Reference method from another class in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, request, public

So I have a class where I create a customer with all necessary information (addresses, phone, emails, etc...) Basically I want to create other classes that do other things with that customer information but reference that class to create a new customer each time.

Here is an example of the class I need to reference:

```
public class Start_Customer
{
    public CreateRequest _request;
    public CreateResponse _response;

    string fax = "(866) 345-3453";
    string website = "www.testersRus.com";
    bool Manage = true;
    int PartnerID = 0;
    string FirstName = "";
    string LastName = "";
    string Email = "";

    public void CreateClient()
    {
        _request = new CreateRequest();
        _request.CommandComment = "";
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        //create a new web service client
        var sw = new SoapCreateStart();

        _response = sw.Customers_Start(new AppHeader(), _request) as CustomerResponse;

        Console.WriteLine(_response.ToString());
    }
```

Now in my new class I am trying to use reference that class and make a new customer and then check and see if certain things were made like the fax number is correct, company is correct and things like that.

Any ideas on how to reference this the correct way WITHOUT making the methods static?

So far I was thinking that I would say:

```
Start_Customer create = Start_Customer();
create = CreateClient();
```

This lets me get to the method but I keep getting null error. Help please!

Comment: Have you debugged calling the CreateClient method? You didn't post the code for the CreateRequest constructor which may be where the problem lies.

Comment: @AaronHawkins, yes the constructor works and I have successfully debugged. And the class in which I create the client works. I am just having a problem accessing that information in different classes.

Comment: From the code you gave, I see no reason why you would have trouble accessing it. Maybe there is an underlying architectural problem? What is the class where you are attaining an instance of Start_Customer where it is failing?  Can you post that code too?

Comment: @AaronHawkins, yes it is within the same project. So I played with it a little more and was able to access the class BUT when I try to just test some values from Start_Customer within the new class I get errors. Is there a special way to go about this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your problem code along with the errors you are recieving? Also, your fields on your Start_Customer class are all private.  Have you tried putting a less restrictive modifier on them such as protected, internal, or public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out. I had to reference each method by saying:

```
create.Create();
```

For example, thanks for the help!